# Intersection of family of sets of real numbers formed by set of rational numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Below is a statement from the book 'Topics in Algebra' by I.N.Herstein.

> For instance, if $S$ is the set of real numbers, and if $T$ is the set of rational numbers, let, for $\alpha \in T$, $A_\alpha =\{x\in S | x\ge\alpha\}$. It is an easy exercise to see that $\cup_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha= S$ whereas $\cap_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha $ is the null set. The sets $A_\alpha$ are not mutually disjoint.

My question is, if $\cap_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha $ is a null set, then $A_\alpha$'s are mutually disjoint sets. But it is stated that it is not a mutually disjoint sets. This may be due to my lack of understanding the statement properly. Can someone explain it?

Comment: Consider the sets $A_n :=\left(0, \frac{1}{n}\right]$  you can see that $$\bigcap_n^\infty A_n= \emptyset$$ but the sets are not mutually disjoint

Comment: Does Herstein give a definition of "mutually disjoint"? Perhaps he used that phrase to mean "pairwise disjoint". Or to mean that some finite union was disjoint from some other finite union.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No. There is no explicit definition for mutually disjoint sets. But there is a definition as follows: “ Two Sets are said to be disjoint if their intersection is empty”. Yes, you may right. He intends to mean some finite intersection was disjoint from other finite intersections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will expand here what i have written in the comment. Let $A_\alpha=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} :  x \ge \alpha\}$ and consider
$$
\bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}} A_\alpha
$$
suppose $ x \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}} A_\alpha$ So $ x \in A_\alpha$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$, but this implies that
$$
x \ge \alpha
$$
for all the rational numbers. This is absurd, so
$$\bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}} A_\alpha= \emptyset$$
but, for any $\alpha \le \beta$ you have
$$
A_\alpha \cap A_\beta = A_\beta \ne \emptyset
$$
The reason this is possible is that  $\bigcap_n A_n = \emptyset$ does not imply that there exists $n,m$ such that $A_n \cap A_m = \emptyset$  (think *e.g.* to the sets $\{1,2\},\{2,3\}, \{1,3\}$)

Moreover being *mutually disjoint* means that for **all** $n \ne m$ $A_n \cap A_m =\emptyset$ that is a stronger property and, in general it is not  true (unless of course there are only 2 sets)